# Arduino Knolleary PubSubClient will publish messages but can't receive them

Tags: arduino, mqtt

I am using the Knolleary PubSubClient to make a connection to my MQTT server. I have been able to successfully authenticate and make a connection after not much work. I can even publish messages to topics. However, the issue I am having is that I can subscribe to topics and get no error, but when I publish to that topic (from mosquitto on my Mac) the callback does not get called and the message to the subscribe topic does not appear to be received. I have tried running a mosquitto subscription to the same topic at the same time, and that does receive the published message. Not sure if there is a problem in my callback code or what is going on here. Any help would be appreciated. Arduino code is below:

```
/*
 Basic MQTT example 

  - connects to an MQTT server
  - publishes "hello world" to the topic "outTopic"
  - subscribes to the topic "inTopic"
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte server[] = { 10, 2, 63, 123 };
byte ip[]     = { 192, 168, 1, 10 };


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.println(topic);
  //convert byte to char
  payload[length] = '\0';
  String strPayload = String((char*)payload);

  Serial.println(strPayload);
  //int valoc = strPayload.lastIndexOf(',');
  //String val = strPayload.substring(valoc+1);
  //Serial.println(val);


}

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, ethClient);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("==STARTING==");

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print("."); 
  }

  //delay(500);
  boolean con = client.connect("1", "3snzzon5dyade:abc", "OBSCURED_FOR_SEC");
  while(con != 1){
    Serial.println("no con-while");
     con = client.connect("1", "3snzzon5dyade:abc", "OBSCURED_FOR_SEC");
  }
  //Serial.println(con);
  if(con){
    Serial.println("got con");
    client.publish("testq","hello world");
    client.subscribe("testq");
  }else Serial.println("no con");

}

void loop()
{
  client.loop();
}
```

Like I said, I can see everything working properly with mosquitto. I have even tried matching up client_ids with no luck. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Naturally, I've left all of my arduino's at work, otherwise I'd test it. If you've not solved it by Monday, I'll give it a go.

Comment: knolleary, thanks for your reply. Could this be something with the broker not being compatible with your library? The same code works with other brokers.

Comment: Which broker implementation are you using?

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking. But it is a custom broker implementation similar to mosquitto server. Is this where the issue might be?

Comment: If the code works against mosquitto, but not against your custom broker implementation, I'd want to look more closely at what your implementation is doing. I'm sure you've done a great job of implementing your broker, but from where I'm sat, it's the one unknown in the question.

Comment: @knolleary any solution to fix this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score -1):

your subscribe topic "testq" must be in an array like

```
char testq[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', 'q', '\0'};
```

be sure to finisht your array with an    ,'\0'

Then you subscribe with:

```
client.subscribe(testq);
```