# Arduino Uno with MQTT Broker

Tags: arduino, mqtt

Is it possible for an Arduino Uno subscribe/connect to MQTT Broker (Mosquitto) without using Ethernet Shield or Wifi Shield?

Actually I have a Wifi module (ESP8266) with me, unfortunately it won't allow me to upload sketch and I keep getting error `error: espcomm_upload_mem failed`

When I interface Arduino Uno with ESP8266 Wifi Module, I construct like this:
[image]

And I have included Generic ESP8266 Module in board manager.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for an Arduino Uno subscribe/connect to MQTT Broker (Mosquitto) without using Ethernet Shield or Wifi Shield?

Of course you need a network to handled a `PubSubClient.h` library for your MQTT Broker.

> I keep getting error error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

I think you have something wrong about the wired or the code, can you post your schematic and your code into your question? so that i get why have this errors.

see this [library](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/).

Comment: @Conard did you connect your module with FTDI/TTL cable into your PC, you should be pined `RX` to `TX` and `TX` to `RX`.

Comment: @Conard see this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014386/mqtt-on-arduino-not-working?lq=1) and read that comments.